# how to containerize a part of application

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose

I am working on a POC where I had to containerize a part of application for eg - I need to containerize  "add to cart" functionality in an e-commerce website, I see a various example https://dzone.com/articles/docker-for-devs-containerizing-your-application  to containerize whole application,but how to do for a part of it where my functionalities has dependency on other code parts as well.

Any pointers will be very helpful as I am totally stuck and don't see similar query anywhere else.

Thanks

Comment: This question is kind of abstract, but the short answer is to create a micro service (or more) for your functionality and then you can containerize these micro services. You can try to see more examples on youtube like this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_azoxefUs_Y&list=PLjAJyXblHWhQ_kt2jYsFPvbMR-zGp33nH&index=2

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, the first thing you need to do is read more about the concept of `microservices` and how it works.

Basically, the idea is decouple your monolithic application into as many services as your want and deploy it separate of each other. Each of this parts will comminicate with other parts by API calls.

There are a lot of benefits of using microservices architecture, and there is no the "better way" to do this, it will depends of how your application works and how your team is engaged.

I can recommend you a couple of link about microservices:

https://medium.com/hashmapinc/the-what-why-and-how-of-a-microservices-architecture-4179579423a9

https://opensource.com/resources/what-are-microservices

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microservices

Answer (score 1):

This is how I'd do it:

1. create a new java/gradle module called "addToCart"
2. extract all functionality related to `"add to cart" functionality` to this single gradle, spring boot module (add relevant dependencies to `build.gradle` and update `settings.gradle` to include the new module. And use `compile("module")` to have dependencies on existing modules brought into your new spring-boot module (note: you can't depend on a module that is a spring boot application - this will fail because spring-boot modules are compiled differently to lib modules without the spring boot plugin).
3. extract any dependencies this new module has on existing code out to another new library module that can be pulled in using a gradle dependency (you're aiming to end up with a Gradle multiproject build). This is required so that existing projects/modules as well as the new one can maintain the same dependencies.
4. use a gradle docker plugin like https://github.com/palantir/gradle-docker OR https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-docker-plugin to create a docker image/container for you (instructions on website). You can do this part manually also.

If you're feeling particularly adventurous you could look into building GraalVM "native images" that are container friendly. Native images start incredibly fast. Because they start so fast you don't actually need to have them running all the time, which can lower your costs. There are trade-offs though. There's a talk from Devoxx Belgium 2019 that goes into details about it here: https://youtu.be/3eoAxphAUIg?t=978

Answer (score 1):

If the application is not build as microservices, it wont actually work. The POC you should be striving for is to decouple it in another seperate application.... Which I guess its much harder and larger scope of the original POC

Comment: our product already has microservices in place,but issue is this particular module uses so many shared code/library from other modules..one way i can think off to place the duplicate codes in my module and spin off completely,but I wont get approval for this approach..just wondering what else I can do

Comment: If its like a library that is ok. Let's say `using your_library` will simply be duplicated. If for example you add to cart microservice uses another microservice or is dependant on it on an assembly level then there is a problem with how the architecture is defined

Comment: okay,if i hv 4 microservices(a,b,c,d) and if i containerize service a and created docker image for it somehow,now a will be calling b,c or d since there is common code or some api call is made from a to them...how can i make use of b,c, & d from my containerize application

Comment: a should depend call b c and d only by API calls. Not assembly dependencies. Generally commincation protocols between processes and and API's but defently not assembly dependant